# How to integrate Uber API?

Tags: api, uber-api

Would it be possible to integrate the Uber APIs into a titanium app?

https://developer.uber.com/docs/tutorial-trip-experiences

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You should be good to go! As long as you have a working [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client that is able to make HTTP requests to the [Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/api-overview) RESTful HTTP server and receive HTTP responses.